# Redefine variables inside if and use it outside like php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass a variables depend on if, I wrote this code

```
var firstFoo  = 2;

$('div').click(function() {
    if(firstFoo == 1){
        var
            var1 = 'var1',
            var2 = 'var2',
            var3 = 'var3';
    }
    else{
        var
            var1 = 'no var1',
            var2 = 'no var2',
            var3 = 'no var3';
    }

    $('<span></span>',{
        'data-var1': var1,
        'data-var2': var2,
        'data-var3': var3
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```

The code works fine see example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xn7xG/

But when I click JSHint I got errors

(var is already defined) & (var used out of scope)

[image]

And I don't know if that mean my code not working as it should on all browsers and situations

**What the right way to write this code above?**

Comment: Note that it's not a _real_ error in that the code "doesn't work", but simply that it's against the settings given to JSHint, which tend to be common coding conventions for JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript there is no concept of block scope, all variables will be declared in the respective function scope/global scope.

In your case you are declaring the same variables twice in the same functional scope, that is the reason for the warning.... even though you declare a variable at the bottom of the page, its scope will be the entire pages because of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) also [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting)

```
var firstFoo = 2;

$('div').click(function () {
    var var1, var2, var3;
    if (firstFoo == 1) {
        var1 = 'var1';
        var2 = 'var2';
        var3 = 'var3';
    } else {
        var1 = 'no var1';
        var2 = 'no var2';
        var3 = 'no var3';
    }

    $('<span></span>', {
        'data-var1': var1,
        'data-var2': var2,
        'data-var3': var3
    }).insertAfter(this);
});
```